PHP cURL Error: Could not resolve host from web server, but works in terminal
I am encountering a persistent issue with cURL in PHP. When running a cURL request from a PHP script via the browser, I get the error: cURL Error: Could not resolve host: api.mailjet.com. However, the same cURL command works perfectly when executed from the terminal.
Steps Taken:
1.  Verified php.ini Configuration:
•   extension=curl is enabled.
•   Confirmed via phpinfo() page that cURL is enabled.
2.  Checked File Permissions and Paths:
•   Set permissions to 755 for /var/www/htdocs and subdirectories.
•   Verified correct paths in the PHP script.
3.  Debugged DNS Resolution and Network Connectivity:
•   Added debugging info to PHP script:

current error:
Resolved IP for api.mailjet.com: api.mailjet.com - DNS resolution failed.
cURL Error: Could not resolve host: api.mailjet.com

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
chdir('/var/www/htdocs');
$ip = gethostbyname('api.mailjet.com');
echo "Resolved IP for api.mailjet.com: $ip<br>";
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \Mailjet\Resources;
$mj = new \Mailjet\Client('your-api-key', 'your-secret-key', true, ['version' => 'v3.1']);
$body = [ /*...*/ ];
$response = $mj->post(Resources::$Email, ['body' => $body]);
if ($response->success()) { echo "Email sent successfully!"; } else { echo "Failed to send email."; var_dump($response->getData()); }
?>

•   Confirmed DNS resolution using nslookup and curl from the terminal:
$ nslookup api.mailjet.com
Server:         108.61.10.10
Address:        108.61.10.10#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   api.mailjet.com
Address: 35.187.79.8

$ curl -v https://api.mailjet.com/v3.1/send
* Host api.mailjet.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 35.187.79.8
*   Trying 35.187.79.8:443...
* Connected to api.mailjet.com (35.187.79.8) port 443
...
Not authorized


Verified Firewall and Network Configurations:
•   Ensured no firewall rules are blocking outgoing connections:

$ doas pfctl -sr | grep block
block drop all


Restarted networking services:

$ sudo sh /etc/netstart

Environment:
•   OS: OpenBSD
•   PHP Version: 8.2
•   Web Server: Apache

nameserver 108.61.10.10
nameserver 9.9.9.9
nameserver 2001:19f0:300:1704::6
nameserver 2620:fe::fe
Any insights into why cURL requests fail in the browser but work in the terminal would be greatly appreciated.
here is the complete error message in the browser:
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api.mailjet.com (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api.mailjet.com/v3.1/send in /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210 
Stack trace:
 #0 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(158): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection()
 #1 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(110): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError()
 #2 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish()
 #3 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke()
 #4 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}()
 #5 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(64): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}()
 #6 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke()
 #7 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}()
 #8 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke()
 #9 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}()
 #10 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(333): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke()
 #11 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(169): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer()
 #12 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(189): GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync()
 #13 /htdocs/vendor/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php/src/Mailjet/Request.php(238): GuzzleHttp\Client->request()
 #14 /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/ClientTrait.php(95): Mailjet\Request->request()
 #15 [internal function]: Mailjet\Request->post()
 #16 /htdocs/vendor/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php/src/Mailjet/Request.php(140): call_user_func()
 #17 /htdocs/vendor/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php/src/Mailjet/Client.php(342): Mailjet\Request->call()
 #18 /htdocs/vendor/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php/src/Mailjet/Client.php(99): Mailjet\Client->_call()
 #19 /htdocs/test-mailjet.php(31): Mailjet\Client->post()
 #20 {main} thrown in /htdocs/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 210


Are you running the webserver in a chroot environment?

Does the PHP script work when executed as CLI?

Are you php curl library uses any kind of proxy?
Can you execute php script in terminal instead of via web?
